# Generating HTML Tables in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, html-table, jsx

I'm generating an HTML table from within JSX. Beautiful. Except that some sections of the table have to be generated conditionally. So, I use a ternary expression, and generate the `<td>`'s.

But JSX only allows a single element to be generated at a time, So, I end up putting `<span>`'s around the conditional part.

But React, or Chrome, or HTML, don't allow spans in `<tbody>`s. Ugh! This is what Chrome's throwing at me:
`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <span> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.`

So what's a guy to do?

Here's some code. Maybe there's a *much* easier way to do this?

```
{card.vars.map(section => {
    return (
        <tbody className="bodySection">
            <td rowSpan={section.vars.length} className="side-title">{section.varTypes}</td>
            {section.vars.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <span key={index}>
                        <td className="fieldname src-data">{item.varName}</td>
                        <td className="fieldvalue src-data">{item.varVal ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</td>
                        {!('transform' in item) ? (
                            <span>
                                <td className="fieldname dest-data">{item.varName}</td>
                                <td className="fieldvalue dest-data">
                                    <input type="text" onChange={this.onValChange.bind(this)} value={item.varVal} />
                                </td>
                            </span>
                        ) : ''}
                    </span>
                );
            })}
        </tbody>
    );
})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using React 16, you can return an array of elements, each with a `key` property.

```
const App = () => [
  <p key="1">React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>,
  <p key="2">React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>,
  <p key="3">React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>,
];
```

Or if you are using React 16.2, you can use the new Fragment syntax

```
const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <p>React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>
    <p>React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>
    <p>React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

NB. Examples from [this article about returning multiple elements](https://pawelgrzybek.com/return-multiple-elements-from-a-component-with-react-16/)

Comment: Thanks @Tony, I'd heard about being able to do that, but without having the syntax, it didn't work when I tried it. (Also, don't think I don't appreciate the emojis so close to Valentine's Day.  >P ) Turns out I'm using 16.2.  Yay!

Comment: SO is making me wait another 2 mins before I can give you the green checkmark. But I tried the Fragment, and it seems to work. So thanks, @Tony!